# hibernate named query error after updating to hibernate 5.0.7 and jpa 2.1

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, named-query

I have very simple named query that use to work before update but now I am getting runtime error.

this is the named query :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FRA_HIER_NODE_TYPE", schema="FRA_DATA")
@NamedQuery(name="NodeType.FetchNodeTypes", query="FROM NodeType")
public class NodeType {
...
```

The exception i see :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: NodeType.FetchNodeTypes
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Try to post more code  of entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you declaring your own `SessionFactory` for Hibernate? I don't remember how Hibernate works with Spring.

But if you have with hibernate config you may have lines like this:

```
<mapping class="com.example.NodeType" />
```

This is removed in Hibernate 5. Instead you have to declare your entities in code when building `SessionFactory`. For example:

```
        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .configure()
            .build();

        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry)
            .addAnnotatedClass(NodeType.class)
            .getMetadataBuilder()
            .applyImplicitNamingStrategy(ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl.INSTANCE)
            .build();

        sessionFactory = metadata
            .getSessionFactoryBuilder()
            .build();
```

See more: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/#bootstrap-native-sessionfactory

Maybe there is some SessionFactory builder for Spring that you now have to configure similary. If so, please post your new config for others.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FRA_HIER_NODE_TYPE", schema="FRA_DATA")
@NamedQuery(name="NodeType.FetchNodeTypes",query="SELECT * FROM NodeType")
```

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FRA_HIER_NODE_TYPE", schema="FRA_DATA")
@NamedQuery(name="NodeType.FetchNodeTypes",query="SELECT n FROM NodeType n")
```